# how to pass back props to Parent Component in wix Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, velo

```
Navigation.push( {                      
            component: {   
                name: "Request",    
                passProps: {
                text: 'Pushed screen',
                bb1: 'anything you want here',
              } }                       
            });
```

Navigation Push pass props to new Screen on in stack, i want to popup the screen with parameters. is there any way to do this in wix Navigation expect redux?

Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using callback methods.

eg:

```
Navigation.push( {                      
            component: {   
                name: "Request",    
                passProps: {
                text: 'Pushed screen',
                bb1: 'anything you want here',
                callback: {(data)=>this._localMethod(data)}
              } }                       
            });   

_localMethod(data) {
 //Here you will get the data, "Data to pass"
}
```

In child class,

call the method,

```
this.props. callback("Data to pass")
```